# How to make one page wider to accommodate a long equation on that page

Tags: equations, width, page

I have an equation (an array with many rows and columns) which is much wider than the text width. Is there a way to make the page as wide as the equation, just for the page that the equation is on?

Comment: You can turn a page around and make it landscape using the `landscape` package. That's what's commonly done with e.g. large tables.

Comment: Thanks, however, the array is really wide, even wider than the height of the page. I was able to make it fit onto a page by using geometry with paperwidth=20in, however, that changes all of the pages, and I would prefer to change only that one page, and also to scale it automatically instead of specifying a fixed width.

Comment: You can use `\newgeometry` and reset it with the same command after the big page.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Is there a way to set the page width according to something on the page? I'm looking at the documentation for newgeometry but I don't see it.

Comment: Not directly. You could put it in a savebox, measure the box and and then use a calculation on that to pass to `\newgeometry`. Not sure this is worth it though. What you're trying to do is kind of crazy, TBH, :) because making arbitrary page sizes within a single document isn't really a terribly sensible thing to do.

Comment: I need to present some equations which are too clumsy to work with by hand to my coworkers, and I only need to get them up on a screen so people can look at them. For that purpose a funny page size is, at most, a minor inconvenience. If it helps me get the message across then it is sensible enough.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned as well, this is not really something you should be doing, and ideally you should figure out a way to format the equation so that it doesn't need to be so wide but without any sense of what you're doing it's hard to advise on that. So here's a solution to what you think you want, but not one that I really endorse.

You can't change the paper size using `\newgeometry`, so the only way I can see to do this is to choose a paper size that is larger than you will ever need, and then adjust the `\texwidth` dynamically using a box. Here's a proof of concept (you don't give any code so maybe there will be complications in your actual use case).

In the code below I've set the paper width to 20" and then used `\newgeometry` to make a normal sized page within that page size. We save this geometry as `normal` so that it can be used again.  You need to do this once at the beginning of the document.

I've then created a command `\adjusttowidth` puts its argument into a box that fits its natural width.  Thanks to wipet for suggesting a much simpler way to do this than my original method. So any large equation will take up just as much room within the 20" as it needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=20in,margin=.5in}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\adjusttowidth}[1]{\par\hbox to\hsize{\hss#1\hss}\par}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{textwidth=7in}
\lipsum
\adjusttowidth{\rule{18in}{1in}}
\lipsum
\adjusttowidth{\rule{12in}{1in}}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good approach, I will give it a try.

Comment: Your `\adjusttowidth` can be defined much more simple: `\def\adjusttowidth#1{\hbox to\hsize{\hss#1\hss}}`.

Comment: @wipet Thanks, that's indeed much simpler. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your request to change margins in single page is typographically incorrect. Totally incorrect. You must re-phrase the equation. Use some variables which substitute parts of the equation, explain these variables etc. Because you didn't give your particular equation where you have the problem, we cannot help more.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Whether it makes sense typographically is a diversion; be it "totally incorrect" or not, I have to get my work done. Also, assertions of impossibility ("we cannot help more") are fragile, as they are disproven by an actual example -- witness the response of A. Munn.

Answer (score 0):

So why not simply use `\rlap` and let your content bleed in the margin, as it were? Not pretty, perhaps, but might be acceptable once.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about rlap. From reading the documentation, I don't see how I would use it on long equations. Can you very briefly sketch it?

Comment: You'd have to provide an example of what exactly you're trying to achieve first … One such long equation, e.g.